# Revert to older commit

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a branch, lets call it branch 1 (B1). I did some work in this branch and finished a task (T1). After that, I had some additions to that task and I added two more commits, T2 and T3. I later decided that T2 and T3 actually belongs in a branch of their own so I branched B1 to a new branch, B2.

What I want to do now is revert B1 back to T1, and drop T2 and T3 from it.

I have tried Reset to Commit, but it always prompts me to PULL the latest version from the online branch since I PUSHED all three commits (T1,T2,T3).

How can I "reset" the online branch as well, so that it is in sync with my local copy (which is the version I want to now PUSH)?